# Word VBA 'file in use' when loading dotx

Tags: vba, ms-word, readonly-attribute

I get the message 'File In Use... locked for editing by another user...' the first time I run the following sub in a Word session. After selecting 'Open a Read Only copy' the macro runs OK. The dotx file has the Read Only and Archive attributes set. Some of my users open Word sessions every few minutes (editing numerous database records one at a time in Word) and this annoys them.

Any ideas if this can be fixed?

Thanks.

```
    Sub Check()
    If Left(ActiveDocument.Attached Template,3) <> "RFP" Then
        With ActiveDocument
            .UpdateStylesOnOpen = True
            .AttachedTemplate = Environ("homedrive") & "\My Documents\RFP Styles.dotx"
        End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to re-create your error (though my dotx also has the Readonly attribute checked). Perhaps your dotx has been inadvertently left open. To close any lingering copies of Windows files, go to Computer Management --> Shared Folders --> Open Files. If you see your dotx file in there, there is a button to Close it.